# Where to find Dell 500 drivers?

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, sound-card

I have [Dell 500 laptop](http://www.dell.com/us/en/bpi/notebooks/emergnb_500/pd.aspx?refid=emergnb_500&s=bpi) and I can't find from where to download its drivers, I have Windows xp intalled, but can't setup the audio driver, and some others.

I hope I can find a place where I can download all this laptop drivers for future use.

Comment: dell drivers always pain ...

Answer (score 3):

They're on the Dell website, just tricky to find. [Here you go](http://support.dell.com/support/downloads/driverslist.aspx?os=WW1&osl=EN&catid=-1&impid=-1&servicetag=&SystemID=VOS_N_500&hidos=WLH&hidlang=en&TabIndex=).

Comment: i had downloaded the audio drive and i found the file is .appliaction and i can not open it please advise

Comment: did you make sure to pick the proper OS (XP). dell drivers are self-extracting archives. you can manually extract the files from these archives, e.g. with Total Commander (CTRL + Page Down),

Comment: you probably picked the download manager link. Here is the direct link for the audio driver: ftp://ftp.us.dell.com/audio/R185411.EXE